# Python loop with groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have an extract of a dataframe below:

```
  ticker       date   open   high    low  close
0     A2M 2020-08-28  18.45  18.71  17.39  17.47
1     A2M 2020-09-04  17.47  17.52  16.53  16.70
2     A2M 2020-09-11  16.70  16.97  16.13  16.45
3     A2M 2020-09-18  16.54  16.77  16.25  16.39
4     A2M 2020-09-25  16.36  17.13  16.32  17.02
5     AAN 2007-06-08  15.29  15.33  14.93  15.07
6     AAN 2007-06-15  15.10  15.23  14.95  15.18
7     AAN 2007-06-22  15.18  15.25  15.12  15.16
8     AAN 2007-06-29  15.14  15.25  15.11  15.22
9     AAN 2007-07-06  15.11  15.33  15.07  15.33
10    AAN 2007-07-13  15.29  15.35  15.12  15.26
11    AAN 2007-07-20  15.25  15.27  15.02  15.10
12    AAN 2007-07-27  15.05  15.15  14.00  14.82
13    AAN 2007-08-03  14.72  14.85  14.47  14.69
14    AAN 2007-08-10  14.56  14.90  14.22  14.54
15    AAN 2007-08-17  14.55  14.79  13.71  14.42
16    AAP 2000-10-06   7.11   7.14   7.10   7.12
17    AAP 2000-10-13   7.13   7.17   7.12   7.17
18    AAP 2000-10-20   7.16   7.25   7.16   7.23
19    AAP 2000-10-27   7.23   7.24   7.22   7.23
20    AAP 2000-11-03   7.16   7.25   7.12   7.25
21    AAP 2000-11-10   7.24   7.24   7.12   7.12
22    ABB 2002-07-26   2.70   3.05   2.60   2.95
23    ABB 2002-08-02   2.92   2.95   2.75   2.80
24    ABB 2002-08-09   2.80   2.84   2.70   2.70
25    ABB 2002-08-16   2.72   2.75   2.70   2.75
26    ABB 2002-08-23   2.71   2.85   2.71   2.75
27    ABB 2002-08-30   2.75   2.75   2.75   2.75
```

I've created the following code to find upPrices vs. downPrices:

```
i = 0
upPrices=[]
downPrices=[]

while i < len(df['close']):
    if i == 0:
        upPrices.append(0)
        downPrices.append(0)
    else:
        if (df['close'][i]-df['close'][i-1])>0:
            upPrices.append(df['close'][i]-df['close'][i-1])
            downPrices.append(0)
        else:
            downPrices.append(df['close'][i]-df['close'][i-1])
            upPrices.append(0)
    i += 1
df['upPrices'] = upPrices
df['downPrices'] = downPrices
```

The result is the following dataframe:

```
 ticker       date   open   high    low  close  upPrices  downPrices
0     A2M 2020-08-28  18.45  18.71  17.39  17.47      0.00        0.00
1     A2M 2020-09-04  17.47  17.52  16.53  16.70      0.00       -0.77
2     A2M 2020-09-11  16.70  16.97  16.13  16.45      0.00       -0.25
3     A2M 2020-09-18  16.54  16.77  16.25  16.39      0.00       -0.06
4     A2M 2020-09-25  16.36  17.13  16.32  17.02      0.63        0.00
5     AAN 2007-06-08  15.29  15.33  14.93  15.07      0.00       -1.95
6     AAN 2007-06-15  15.10  15.23  14.95  15.18      0.11        0.00
7     AAN 2007-06-22  15.18  15.25  15.12  15.16      0.00       -0.02
8     AAN 2007-06-29  15.14  15.25  15.11  15.22      0.06        0.00
9     AAN 2007-07-06  15.11  15.33  15.07  15.33      0.11        0.00
10    AAN 2007-07-13  15.29  15.35  15.12  15.26      0.00       -0.07
11    AAN 2007-07-20  15.25  15.27  15.02  15.10      0.00       -0.16
12    AAN 2007-07-27  15.05  15.15  14.00  14.82      0.00       -0.28
13    AAN 2007-08-03  14.72  14.85  14.47  14.69      0.00       -0.13
14    AAN 2007-08-10  14.56  14.90  14.22  14.54      0.00       -0.15
15    AAN 2007-08-17  14.55  14.79  13.71  14.42      0.00       -0.12
16    AAP 2000-10-06   7.11   7.14   7.10   7.12      0.00       -7.30
17    AAP 2000-10-13   7.13   7.17   7.12   7.17      0.05        0.00
18    AAP 2000-10-20   7.16   7.25   7.16   7.23      0.06        0.00
19    AAP 2000-10-27   7.23   7.24   7.22   7.23      0.00        0.00
20    AAP 2000-11-03   7.16   7.25   7.12   7.25      0.02        0.00
21    AAP 2000-11-10   7.24   7.24   7.12   7.12      0.00       -0.13
22    ABB 2002-07-26   2.70   3.05   2.60   2.95      0.00       -4.17
23    ABB 2002-08-02   2.92   2.95   2.75   2.80      0.00       -0.15
24    ABB 2002-08-09   2.80   2.84   2.70   2.70      0.00       -0.10
25    ABB 2002-08-16   2.72   2.75   2.70   2.75      0.05        0.00
26    ABB 2002-08-23   2.71   2.85   2.71   2.75      0.00        0.00
27    ABB 2002-08-30   2.75   2.75   2.75   2.75      0.00        0.00
```

Unfortunately the logic is not correct. The `upPrices` and `downPrices` need to be for each ticker. At the moment, you can see that in rows 5, 16 and 22 it compares the previous close from another ticker. Essentially, I need this formula to `groupby` or some other means to restart at each ticker. However, when I try add in groupby it returns index length mismatch errors.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition of `groupby` is correct. `groupby` ticker then `diff` the closing prices. You can use `where` to get it separated into the style of up and down columns you wanted. Plus, now no more loop! For something that just requires "basic" math operations a vectorized approach is much better.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"ticker":["A2M","A2M","A2M","A2M","A2M","AAN","AAN","AAN","AAN"], "close":[17.47,16.7,16.45,16.39,17.02,15.07,15.18,15.16,15.22]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["diff"] = df.groupby("ticker")["close"].diff()
df["upPrice"] = df["diff"].where(df["diff"] > 0, 0)
df["downPrice"] = df["diff"].where(df["diff"] < 0, 0)
del df["diff"]
print(df)
```

Comment: That's great, thanks! For my own learning, is it also possible to do it in a loop? How would I do that?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But (and this might sound odd) for your own learning you should NOT try to figure it out. A BIG part of learning Pandas is learning that loops are not the way to do things. Pandas bread and butter is vectorization. Figuring out how to do this as a loop will just reinforce bad habits